# No such external ID currently defined in the system

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-6

** No matching record found for external id 'model_oemedical_lab_group' in field 'Object'**

- i am a beginner in openerp. i was tried to do my own customizations
  in some simple modules. once i was download the mode called
- oemedical
- i can't able to install oemedical_lab.That modul shows some error when i was try to install it.please help me out.I am stuck with this.
- thanking you

> oemedical_lab.py

```
enter code here
import time

from openerp.osv import fields, orm
 class oemedical_patient (orm.Model):
_name = "oemedical.patient"
_inherit = "oemedical.patient"

_columns = {
    'lab_test_ids': fields.one2many(
        'oemedical.patient.lab.test', 'patient_id', 'Lab Tests Required'),
}

 class test_type (orm.Model):
_name = "oemedical.test_type"
_description = "Type of Lab test"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char(
        'Test', size=128,
        help="Test type, eg X-Ray, hemogram,biopsy..."),
    'code': fields.char(
        'Code', size=128,
        help="Short name - code for the test"),
    'info': fields.text(
        'Description'),
    'product_id': fields.many2one(
        'product.product', 'Service', required=True),
    'critearea': fields.one2many(
        'oemedical_test.critearea', 'test_type_id', 'Test Cases'),


}
_sql_constraints = [
    ('code_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'The Lab Test code must be unique')]


class lab (orm.Model):
_name = "oemedical.lab"
_description = "Lab Test"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char(
        'ID', size=128, help="Lab result ID"),
    'test': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.test_type', 'Test type', help="Lab test type"),
    'patient': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.patient',
        'Patient',
        help="Patient ID"),
    'pathologist': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.physician',
        'Pathologist',
        help="Pathologist"),
    'requestor': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.physician',
        'Physician',
        help="Doctor who requested the test"),
    'results': fields.text(
        'Results'),
    'diagnosis': fields.text(
        'Diagnosis'),
    'critearea': fields.one2many(
        'oemedical_test.critearea', 'oemedical_lab_id', 'Test Cases'),
    'date_requested': fields.datetime(
        'Date requested'),
    'date_analysis': fields.datetime(
        'Date of the Analysis'),
}

_defaults = {
    'date_requested': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'date_analysis': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'name': lambda self, cr, uid, context: self.pool['ir.sequence'].get(
        cr, uid, 'oemedical.lab'),
}

_sql_constraints = [
    ('id_uniq', 'unique (name)', 'The test ID code must be unique')]


    class oemedical_lab_test_units(orm.Model):
      _name = "oemedical.lab.test.units"
      _columns = {
       'name': fields.char('Unit', size=25),
       'code': fields.char('Code', size=25),
    }
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq', 'unique(name)', 'The Unit name must be unique')]


   class oemedical_test_critearea(orm.Model):
_name = "oemedical_test.critearea"
_description = "Lab Test Critearea"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Test', size=64),
    'result': fields.text('Result'),
    'normal_range': fields.text('Normal Range'),
    'units': fields.many2one('oemedical.lab.test.units', 'Units'),
    'test_type_id': fields.many2one('oemedical.test_type', 'Test type'),
    'oemedical_lab_id': fields.many2one('oemedical.lab', 'Test Cases'),
    'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence'),
}
_defaults = {
    'sequence': lambda *a: 1,
}
_order = "sequence"


class oemedical_patient_lab_test(orm.Model):
_name = 'oemedical.patient.lab.test'

def _get_default_dr(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    partner_id = self.pool.get('res.partner').search(
        cr, uid, [('user_id', '=', uid)], context=context)
    if partner_id:
        dr_id = self.pool.get('oemedical.physician').search(
            cr, uid, [('name', '=', partner_id[0])], context=context)
        if dr_id:
            return dr_id[0]
        # else:
        #    raise osv.except_osv(_('Error !'),
        #            _('There is no physician defined ' \
        #                    'for current user.'))
    else:
        return False

_columns = {
    'name': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.test_type', 'Test Type'),
    'date': fields.datetime(
        'Date'),
    'state': fields.selection(
        [('draft', 'Draft'),
         ('tested', 'Tested'),
         ('cancel', 'Cancel')],
        'State', readonly=True),
    'patient_id': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.patient', 'Patient'),
    'doctor_id': fields.many2one(
        'oemedical.physician',
        'Doctor',
        help="Doctor who Request the lab test."),
    # 'invoice_status' : fields.selection(
    # [('invoiced','Invoiced'),
    # ('tobe','To be Invoiced'),
    # ('no','No Invoice')],'Invoice Status'),
}

_defaults = {
    'date': lambda *a: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
    'state': lambda *a: 'draft',
    'doctor_id': _get_default_dr,
    # 'invoice_status': lambda *a: 'tobe',
}
```

> oemedical_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<openerp>
<data>

<!-- Lab test units -->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_lab_unit_form">
        <field name="name">Test Units</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.lab.test.units</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Test Unit">
                <field name="name" required="1"/>
                <field name="code"/>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_lab_unit_tree">
        <field name="name">Test Units</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.lab.test.units</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Test Unit">
                <field name="name"/>
                <field name="code"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_lab_unit">
        <field name="name">Lab Testing Units</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">oemedical.lab.test.units</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>
```

Lab Test Requests
            oemedical.patient.lab.test
            form
            
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                
            
        
           
            Lab Test Requests
            oemedical.patient.lab.test
            tree

```
    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_lab_test_request">
        <field name="name">Lab Requests</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">oemedical.patient.lab.test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="oemedical_action_lab_test_request" id="oemedical_labtest_request" parent="oemedical_laboratory_menu"/>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_draft_lab_test_request">
        <field name="name">Draft Requests</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">oemedical.patient.lab.test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=','draft')]</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="oemedical_action_draft_lab_test_request" id="oemedical_draft_labtest_request" parent="oemedical_labtest_request"/>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_today_draft_lab_test_request">
        <field name="name">Today's Draft Requests</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">oemedical.patient.lab.test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('state','=','draft'),('date','&gt;=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:01')),('date','&lt;=',time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))]</field>
    </record>

    <menuitem action="oemedical_action_today_draft_lab_test_request" id="oemedical_today_draft_labtest_request" parent="oemedical_labtest_request"/>


    <record id="view_oemedical_lab_test_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lab Tests Requests</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.patient.lab.test</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Lab Tests Requests">

                <separator orientation="vertical"/>
                    <field name="name" select="1"/>
                    <field name="date" select="1"/>
                    <field name="patient_id" select="1"/>
                    <field name="doctor_id" select="1"/>
                    <field name="state" select="1"/>
                <newline/>

            </search>
        </field>
    </record>
```

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_patient_view_lab_test">
        <field name="name">Patient Lab Test</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.patient</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="oemedical.view_oemedical_patient_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <notebook position="inside">
                <page string="Lab Tests">
                    <field name="lab_test_ids" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                        <tree string="Lab Tests">
                            <field name="name" required="1"/>
                            <field name="doctor_id"/>
                            <field name="date"/>
                            <field name="state"/>
                        </tree>
                        <form string="Lab Tests">
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="doctor_id"/>
                            <field name="date"/>
                            <field name="state"/>
                        </form>
                    </field>
                </page>
            </notebook>
        </field>
    </record>
```

```
            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_test_view">
                    <field name="name">Lab test</field>
                    <field name="model">oemedical.test_type</field>
                    <field name="type">form</field>
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                            <form string="Lab Test">
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Main Info">
                        <field name="name" required="1"></field>
                        <field name="code"></field>
                        <field name="critearea" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                <tree string="Test Cases">
                    <field name="sequence"/>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="normal_range"/>
                    <field name="units"/>
                </tree>
                <form string="Test Cases">
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="units"/>
                    <field name="sequence"/>
                    <newline/>
                    <field name="normal_range"/>
                </form>
            </field>
            <field name="product_id"/>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Extra Info">
                        <field name="info"></field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
                            </form>
                    </field>
            </record>



            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_test_tree">
                    <field name="name">Lab test types list</field>
                    <field name="model">oemedical.test_type</field>
                    <field name="type">tree</field>
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                            <tree string='Lab test type'>
                                    <field name="name"></field>
                                    <field name="code"></field>
                            </tree>
                    </field>
            </record>


            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_form_test">
                    <field name="name">New Type of Lab test</field>
                    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                    <field name="res_model">oemedical.test_type</field>
                    <field name="view_type">form</field>
                    <field name="view_id" ref="oemedical_test_view"/>
            </record>

    <record id="view_oemedical_lab_test_type_search" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">oemedical.test_type.select</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.test_type</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Lab Test Types">

                <separator orientation="vertical"/>
                    <field name="name" select="1"/>
                    <field name="code" select="1"/>
            <newline/>

            </search>
        </field>
    </record>


    <menuitem action="oemedical_action_form_test" id="oemedical_conf_test" parent="oemedical_conf_laboratory" />





            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_lab_view">
                    <field name="name">Lab Test</field>
                    <field name="model">oemedical.lab</field>
                    <field name="type">form</field>
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                            <form string="Laboratory Test">
                <notebook>
                    <page string="Main Info">
                        <field name="name" required="1"></field>
                        <field name="test" required="1"></field>
                        <field name="date_analysis"></field>
                        <newline/>
                        <field name="patient" required="1"></field>
                        <field name="pathologist"></field>
                        <newline/>
                        <field name="date_requested"></field>
                        <field name="requestor" required="1"></field>

                    <field name="critearea" colspan="4" nolabel="1">
                        <tree editable="top" string="Test Cases">
                            <field name="sequence"/>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="result"/>
                            <field name="normal_range"/>
                            <field name="units"/>
                        </tree>
                        <form string="Test Cases">
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="result"/>
                            <field name="units"/>
                            <field name="normal_range"/>
                        </form>
                    </field>

                    </page>
                    <page string="Extra Info">
                        <field name="results"></field>
                        <newline/>
                        <field name="diagnosis"></field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
                            </form>
                    </field>
            </record>



            <record model="ir.ui.view" id="oemedical_lab_tree">
                    <field name="name">Lab test type</field>
                    <field name="model">oemedical.lab</field>
                    <field name="type">tree</field>
                    <field name="arch" type="xml">
                            <tree string='Lab test type'>
                                    <field name="name"></field>
                                    <field name="test"></field>
                                    <field name="patient"></field>
                                    <field name="date_analysis"></field>
                            </tree>
                    </field>
            </record>

            <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="oemedical_action_tree_lab">
                    <field name="name">Lab Tests Results</field>
                    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                    <field name="res_model">oemedical.lab</field>
                    <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
                    <field name="view_id" ref="oemedical_lab_tree"/>
            </record>

    <menuitem action="oemedical_action_tree_lab" id="oemedical_action_lab_tree" parent="oemedical_laboratory_menu" sequence="2"/>



<act_window domain="[('patient', '=', active_id)]" id="act_patient_lab_history" name="Lab Reports" res_model="oemedical.lab" src_model="oemedical.patient"/>

    <record id="view_oemedical_lab_test_results_filter" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Lab Tests Results</field>
        <field name="model">oemedical.lab</field>
        <field name="type">search</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <search string="Search Lab Tests Results">

                <separator orientation="vertical"/>
                    <field name="name" select="1"/>
                    <field name="test" select="1"/>
                    <field name="patient" select="1"/>
                    <field name="date_analysis" select="1"/>
                <newline/>

            </search>
        </field>
    </record>



</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

The model_oemedical_lab_group model doesn't seem to be in the code snippets you have posted at all and this format looks like the format used in the security csv file.  I would check that file.  Ensure the model exists and if it does but in a different module, ensure that module is declared in the depends list in your `__openerp__`.py file.

Comment: thank you so much... its really helpful.in  __openerp__  file 'depends': ['oemedical_emr'] and ##Data has  "data": [
        # view has errors, please correct before enabling....
        # 'views/oemedical_lab_view.xml',
        # not checked yet....
        # 'views/oemedical_lab_report.xml',
        'security/oemedical_security.xml',
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'oemedical_menu.xml',]   is it  make any errors?? i am totally stuck with this stuff... please give a hand.